# Covering fat objects with fat objects

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convexity, convex-geometry

The family of rectangles has the *cover property*, i.e.:

For every $R\geq 1$, $k\geq 1$: every rectangle with aspect ratio $kR$ can be exactly covered by $\lceil k\rceil$ (possibly overlapping) rectangles of aspect ratio at most $R$.

I am trying to generalize this property to arbitrary convex shapes, using the following natural generalization of the aspect ratio concept:

*(side length of smallest containing square) / (side length of largest contained square)*

This factor can be termed *slimness factor*, as many papers define an "$R$-fat shape" as a shape for which this factor is at most $R$.   So, for example, the slimness factor of a square is 1, the slimness factor of a circle is $\sqrt 2$, etc.

The slimness factor of a rectangle is identical to its aspect ratio, so this is indeed a proper generalization of the aspect ratio concept. However, the cover property is not true when the slimness factor is used instead of the aspect ratio.

For example, taking $R=1$, the only shape with slimness factor 1 is a square, but obviously most convex shapes cannot be exactly covered by a finite number of squares.

So, my question is: **Does there exist an $R$ such that every convex shape with slimness factor $kR$ can be exactly covered by $\lceil k\rceil$ convex shapes of slimness factor at most $R$**?

Comment: A bit related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/134407/covering-of-the-plane-with-manholes

Comment: Are the areas of all the shapes supposed to be the same?

Comment: @BenBarber not necessarily.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I'm having trouble understanding.  For example, what does "obviously most convex shapes cannot be covered by a finite number of squares" mean?

Comment: @BenBarber For example, how can you cover a circle with a finite number of squares? Maybe it was unclear that the cover must be exact - i.e. the union of the covering shapes must be equal to the covered shape (not larger than it). I added the word "exactly" to make this clear.

Comment: "The slimness factor of a rectangle is identical to its aspect ratio" --- is this true? If you use a square rotated at $\pi/4$, you may cover an $a\times b$ rectangle by a square with side length $(a+b)/\sqrt2$...